# Buscar informações do banco de dados, selecionando um campo

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, html5

Como selecionar um campo e puxar as informações referente a ele?

Por exemplo, eu queria selecionar um usuário e quando eu selecionasse aparece nos campos tipo Nome, Endereço, cpf e etc tudo preenchido, buscando essas informações do banco de dados.

Eu estou usando ASP .NET, C#, HTML, javascript.

Se alguém puder dar uma força aí, agradeço.

Comment: Cara falta mais clareza na pergunta. Como você deseja selecionar esse campo e onde responder? Um select acho que resolve a seleção do campo, tipo: select campo1 from tabela. Esse(s) resultado(s) você pega e coloca em um textbox, label e etc. Agora, pela pergunta não consegui entender bem.

Comment: Você quer selecionar esses dados de onde exatamente? Está usando algum banco de dados? Qual? Se é banco de dados, quais as tabelas que você quer buscar os dados? Se não é banco de dados, que estrutura de dados está utilizando? Muitas perguntas precisam ser respondidas para que possamos responder a sua...

Comment: Deixa eu tentar explicar melhor, eu estou fazendo um sistema web, tem um campo onde eu seleciono o usuário, ao selecionar o usuário eu queria que trouxesse todas as informações referentes a esse usuário, como por exemplo Nome, Endereço, cpf. Deu pra entender?

Comment: Eu queria puxar essas informações do banco de dados. Esse usuário teria sido cadastrado anteriormente.

Comment: Estou fazendo um dropdown que puxa todos os usuários cadastrados, ao selecionar um, puxasse todas essas informações do banco de dados, preenchendo esses campos.

Comment: Certo, pegar as informações no banco de dados do lado do servidor você consegue? Você só quer saber como fazer pra buscar e mostrar?

Comment: Pegar as informações do lado do servidor eu consigo, quero jogar essas informações para o lado do usuário, para ser exibido na tela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isso, você pode fazer um método que retorne todos os usuários em `Json` em seu `controller`, ficaria assim:

**Método ObterPorId no controller:**

```
    public JsonResult ObterPorId(int id)
        {  
 //ViewBag para listar todos os usuários
 ViewBag.Usuarios = Context.Usuarios.ToList()
                .Select(e => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = e.UsuarioId.ToString(),
                    Text = e.Nome,                    
                });
            var usuarios= context.usuarios.where(u => u.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            return Json(usuarios, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

E em sua `View`, você pode utilizar a consulta `Ajax`, como o @KaduAmaral sugeriu, ficando assim:

**View:**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    Usuarios:
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlUsuarios", new SelectList(ViewBag.Usuarios, "value", "text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>


id: <input id="id" name="id" /><br/>
Nome: <input id="nome" name="nome" /><br />
Cpf: <input id="cpf" name="cpf" />

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#ddlUsuarios').change(function () {
           // Valor atual selecionado
           var user = $(this).val();
           $.ajax({
               url: @Url.Content("~/") +'Usuarios/ObterPorId',
               type: 'GET',
               dataType: 'json',
               // No servidor com C# vai receber como Request.QueryString["usuario"]
               data: { id: user },
               success: function (json) {
                   // "nome" deve ser o id do campo input ex:
                   // <input type="text" name="nome-do-usuario" id="nome">
                   // Segue mesma regra para demais campos
                   //Lembrando que aqui e sensitive case, ou seja, diferenciando letras maiúsculas de minúsculas. 
                   $('#id').val(json.id);
                   $('#nome').val(json.nome);
                   $('#cpf').val(json.cpf);

               },
               error: function (e) {
                   alert("Deu algo errado, examine o console para mais detalhes");
                   console.log(e);
               }
           });
       });

    </script>
}
```

Comment: Na verdade eu queria fazer na mesma tela, na tela teria o campo dropdown para selecionar o usuário, só que na mesma tela teria outros campos tipo Nome, Endereço e cpf, porém vazio. Ao selecionar o usuário no dropdown esses campos seriam preenchidos, com as informações trazidas do banco de dados referente a esse usuário, cadastrado anteriormente.

Comment: Seria sim. Mas pelo que estou vendo você precisa que busque por um `DropDownList`?
Assim altero somente uma vez.

Comment: Na verdade eu queria fazer na mesma tela, na tela teria o campo dropdown para selecionar o usuário, só que na mesma tela teria outros campos tipo Nome, Endereço e cpf, porém vazio. Ao selecionar o usuário no dropdown esses campos seriam preenchidos, com as informações trazidas do banco de dados referente a esse usuário, cadastrado anteriormente.

Comment: Editei a resposta com base na resposta do @KaduAmaral. Teste agora e veja se é isso que precisa.

Comment: No que vc fez ao selecionar o usuário, é preenchido os campos id, nome e cpf automaticamente?

Comment: Exatamente @Italo.

Comment: Só não entendi de onde vc puxa os dados.

Comment: Estou utilizando o Metodo ObterPorId para buscar o usuário selecionado no `DropDownList`. E estou preenchendo o `DropDownList` pela `ViewBag.Usuarios`.

Comment: Se eu fosse pegar esses dados no banco de dados como ficaria?

Comment: Da forma que eu coloquei, ele está buscando no banco de dados, na tabela usuários.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize uma requisição ajax para enviar a requisição com os dados do usuário selecionado:

```
// <select id="usuario">...</select>
// Instrução será chamada assim que o campo usuario for alterado
$(document).on('change', '#usuario', function(event){
    // Valor atual selecionado
    var user = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'endereco/da/pagina.aspx',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        // No servidor com C# vai receber como Request.QueryString["usuario"]
        data: {usuario: user}, 
        success: function(json){
            // "nome" deve ser o id do campo input ex:
            // <input type="text" name="nome-do-usuario" id="nome">
            // Segue mesma regra para demais campos
            $('#nome').val(json.nome);
            $('#cpf').val(json.cpf);
            $('#endereco').val(json.endereco);
        },
        error: function (e){
            alert("Deu algo errado, examine o console para mais detalhes");
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
});
```

Utilizando [jQuery](https://jquery.com) você obtêm um ótimo resultado com poucas linhas. Porém você pode obter o mesmo resultado com Javascript puro,
basta estuar um pouco sobre [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/). E para informar os valores nos campos você pode usar uma instrução similar a:

```
var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
document.getElementById("nome").value = json.nome;
```

Eu não programo em ASP.NET, então não estarei postando código do servidor, mas para saber mais sobre como como codificar um json consulte a documentação da [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Cara, difícil responder sua pergunta porque tem muita pouca informação de como está fazendo sua aplicação e como está acessando os dados, mas acredito que o que você queira é algo tipo o exemplo do link a seguir.

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ajax_database.asp

Comment: É mais ou menos isso, só que eu vou selecionar um usuário e puxar as informações do banco de dados e preencher os campos <input type:text>